# Limit max number of annotations depending on device type

Tags: ios, performance, mapkit

I'm developing an iOS mapping application that displays a large number of moving annotations. There's a device dependent threshold at which MKMapView falls over due to too many annotations. Short of trial and error running on various iPhones and iPads, is there a way to determine this threshold at runtime? The idea is to limit the number of annotations based on the device type to ensure a performant user experience. Some ideas that come to mind include

- Programmatically check the refresh rate
- Programmatically check the CPU load

To summarize, how does one limit the number of display objects (annotations, overlays) based on the device's capabilities (namely the CPU) in programmatic way?

Comment: damn those little pokemons!!! *smile*

Comment: eh...maybe keep an eye on the `didRecieveMemoryWarning()` and stop adding when that fires? I don't know of a way to programmatically check the CPU.

Comment: why not cluster them instead of drawing all of them on screen ?